# MVC Core Repository to Join Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have Customer transactional table with multiple lookup tables with foreign keys. We want to see the 3 table joined together. Should a Repository ever join tables together, or is it only used for reading single tables?

Also if so, what does the example repository place data into? I heard it cannot know about Viewmodels etc, so what object data type would the results go into?

**Repository:**

```
void GetByCustomerTransactionId()
{
   var result = from ct in CustomerTransaction
    join pt in ProductType on pt.ProductTypeId equals ct.ProductTypeId 
    join ss in Status on s.StatusId equals ct.StatusId 
    select new all fields
}
```

**Models:**

```
public class CustomerTransaction
{
    public int CustomerTransactionId{ get; set; },
    public int ProductTypeId {get; set; }, //joins to ProductTypeTable
    public int StatusID {get; set; },  //joins to StatusTypeTable
    public string DateOfPurchase{ get; set; },
    public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; },
}

public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeId{ get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; },
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; },
}

public class StatusType
{
    public int StatusId{ get; set; }
    public string StatusName{ get; set; },
    public string Description{ get; set; },

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to establish One-To-Many Relationships in ASP.NET Core is the `Fluent API`

```
public class CustomerTransaction
{
    public int CustomerTransactionId { get; set; }
    public string DateOfPurchase{ get; set; }
    public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; }

    // relationships
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; } 

    public StatusType StatusType { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }  
}

public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    // relationships
    public ICollection<CustomerTransaction> CustomerTransactions { get; set; }
}

public class StatusType
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // relationships
    public ICollection<CustomerTransaction> CustomerTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

Then simply use `Include` to properly join them together in your result.

```
public void GetByCustomerTransactionId(int id)
{
     var result = context.CustomerTransaction.Where(x=>x.CustomerTransactionId == id)
     .Include(i=>i.ProductType)
     .Include(i=>i.StatusType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering there are foreign key constraints on the tables, you can simply do this without having to do any joins yourself

```
public class CustomerTransaction
{
    public int CustomerTransactionId{ get; set; },
    public int ProductTypeId {get; set; }, //joins to ProductTypeTable
    public int StatusID {get; set; },  //joins to StatusTypeTable
    public string DateOfPurchase{ get; set; },
    public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; },
    // Add this
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set;}
    public StatusType StatusType { get; set;} 
}
```

and then on your repository simply get the CustomerTransation and it will return the joined tables too, based on their foreign key

```
CustomerTransaction GetByCustomerTransactionId(int id)
{
   var result = ct.CustomerTransaction.Where(x => x.CustomerTransactionId == id).ToList()
  return result;
}
```

That will give you your CustomerTransactions, their StatusType and ProductType

Comment: that's interesting, how do I just get the customer transaction columnsdata then? without the related product types and status types as you mentioned, for future learning, Thanks-

Comment: Do you mean the customer Transation data without the Status type and product type?

Comment: correct, customer Transation data without the Status type and product type

Comment: Thats not possible unless you mark it as `[NotMapped]` or you remove it from the Entity but then you won't be able to get a join of all 3 tables

Comment: you don't need to specify `virtual` in ASP.NET Core

Comment: you're right @mark333...333...333, habits die hard. Edited the code

Comment: the person above has this in code,      .Include(i=>i.ProductType)
     .Include(i=>i.StatusType);, is that extra additional code?